# Devops Shutdown services

Tags: sql-server, powershell, loops, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to work out a way in DevOps on pipelines to be able to shut down a Windows service when its safe to do so.
E.g. We have a service that runs constantly but sometimes we need to gracefully shut it down, we do this via MSSQL by setting something in a table to true then the service will gracefully close its connections and then will update a table to say it's ok to stop the service, Manually this is okay but we want to automate the process via DevOps pipeline release

So the idea I have is following:

1. Send update set command on table to set to true so can be shut down
2. Monitor a table till it has row for that service using a where name = service name
3. Send a command either from PowerShell or pipeline to say okay to shut down service

1 and 3 seem pretty simple however, for the life of me I can't seem to work out how to check a table constantly till it has a row

I found I could do

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ShutdownLog WHERE Name = 'ServiceName') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsEmpty;
```

Which basically shows is empty once, but how do i loop this query till it has data?

My plan would be to run a stored procedure that would do option 1 then run loop option 2 then return True if met, then in DevOps I would just send a command to storedprocedure to see `if = true` I guess..

Comment: I'd guess you could a loop in powershell to poll the table.

Comment: A better way is to implement cancelation support in your service. If the OS decides to stop your service for some reason, your custom code is not triggerd to gracefully shutdown. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-cancellation-requests-by-polling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the powershell `Invoke-Sqlcmd` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#examples))

With the following query's:

```
UPDATE Table
    SET Column = 'True'
Where Name = 'StopService'
```

Wait query:

```
 -- Loop until there is a row with value = 'ServiceName'

DECLARE @ServiceName VARCHAR(100) = 'YourServiceName'
DECLARE @Index INT = 0
DECLARE @MaxTries INT = 10

WHILE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ShutdownLog WHERE Name = @ServiceName)
BEGIN
    
    IF @Index > @MaxTries
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Max retries exceeded' as Message
        BREAK;
    END

    -- sleep for 10 Seconds
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

SELECT CONCAT(@ServiceName, ' was stopped')  as Message
```

Comment: Many thanks this seems to work, but had to change a little, as it seemed to just say completed successfully if not found, but I replaced And index to OR index and it run till max retry.  but how can i have it say there is a row there i just get a endless loop and if i add print statement i get loads of lines saying there is a row, if i search for something that not in table it does it 10 times like it should

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help on this, it's still not fully working, I tried updating it and testing different ways but its basically at the moment doing the following:

Service name = BOB (this won't appear in the table)
Loops table for bob not found so then comes up with Max Retries exceeded then BOB was stopped 
so then my PS script sees it was stopped and then closes down service, but it didn't stop 

If i get rid of last line and search for a service that is in log i get 
 Commands completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview), Azure Functions is an event driven, compute-on-demand experience that extends the existing Azure application platform with capabilities to implement code triggered by events occurring in Azure or third party service as well as on-premises systems. Azure Functions allows developers to take action by connecting to data sources or messaging solutions thus making it easy to process and react to events.

We could do that easy with Azure function bind storage queue message.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp